# Java GradeCalculator - While loop not working correctly

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm writing a program where a user enters a number of students in a class, the number of exams taken in the class, then enters each student's names and exam scores. The program then calculates that student's grade and assigns them a corresponding letter grade. Then finally, it adds their scores to a classSum, calculates the average class score and displays it.

This is what I have so far:
    public class GradeCalculator {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int classSum = 0;       // variable used to hold sum of entire classes exams
        int classExams = 0;     // variable used to hold number of exams taken by whole class

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Gradecalculator!");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of students:");
        int students = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of exams:");
        int exams = s.nextInt();   

        int i = 0;
        int studentnumber = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        while (i < students) {    // loop until it matches number of students entered above
            i++;
            sum = 0;

            System.out.println("Enter student " + studentnumber++ + "'s name :");
            String studentname = s.next();

            System.out.println("Enter exam scores :");

            int input = 0;
            for (; input < exams; input++) {   
                int n = s.nextInt();
                sum+=n;

                if (n < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter: ");  //if one of the scores entered is     negative, display message
                }
            }

            double average = sum/exams;        // assign letter grade based on average of exams
            if (average <= 100 && average >= 90) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 4 stars! ****");
            } if (average <= 89 && average >= 80) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 3 stars! ***");
            } if (average <= 79 && average >= 70) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 2 stars! **");
            } if (average <= 69 && average >= 60) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 1 star! *");
            } if (average <= 59) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 0 stars!");
            }

            classSum += sum;             // add sum of this student's scores to the classSum
            classExams += exams;   // add exams taken by this student to amount of exams taken by whole class
        }

        int classAverage = classSum/classExams; // compute class average
        System.out.println("Class statistics:");
        System.out.println("\tAverage: " + classAverage);
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Welcome to Gradecalculator!

Please enter the number of students:

2

Please enter the number of exams:

3

Enter student 1's name :

sam

Enter exam scores :

80 80 80

Letter grade: B

sam gets 3 stars! ***

Enter student 2's name :

joe

Enter exam scores :

90 90 90

Class statistics:

Average: 125
```

As you can see, after the first student, entering the name and exam scores does not display the next student's letter grade as the loop is supposed to do. Also, the class average is not being calculated correctly. I'm at a bit of a loss here with where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Huh? I did accept the answer because he helped me solved my issue. I didn't want to keep bothering the same guy about the next problem I had, which is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set sum to 0 each turn of the loop

```
while (i < students) { // loop until it matches number of students entered above
    i++;
    sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter student " + studentnumber++ + "'s name :"); String studentname = s.next();
    // [...]
```

Comment: The thing is I need to add each students scores to the class sum in order to calculate the class average in the last step.

Comment: Yes, its still the case with classSum, sum is just a temp  variable for storing the current student grades

Comment: Ah, ok. I added the sum=0 to the beginning of the loop as you directed. Now what happens is after I enter the first students scores, it gives me the correct letter grade and message but then won't allow me to enter the next student's name (it jumps right to entering the next student's scores instead). Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Could you edit your post with these new informations please ?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I simply entered input wrong. I will update the OP further soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, I updated the OP to reflect current code. Now my issue is that I need it so that if a user enters a negative exam score (ex: 90 95 -90) the program doesn't add those scores to classSum, and tells them to re-enter their scores ("Invalid exam scores, reenter"). As it stands, when I enter a negative score it says to re-enter scores but doesn't actually get rid of the incorrect entry (and gives them a letter grade of F. It should not give a letter grade at all if a negative score is entered).

Comment: It's another issue. Maybe another question ? What have you tried yet ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll make another question, thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not reset (assign zero to) `sum` inside the loop. This means that after Sam, when it's Joe's turn, his scores get added on top of sam's! For this reason, you have to reset `sum` before the score reading and adding loop.

This is also why it didn't print anything about Joe. Since you basically have the sum of the scores of six exams divided by only three, you get a result that's more than a hundred, and that is not covered by any of your `if` statements.